# Can't load my locally hosted Apache server because on security error

Tags: apache, web-services, http, https, xampp

My local env has been working for months, but this morning I tried to load it and got this error:

claims.dev uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed. The certificate is not valid for the name claims.dev. The certificate expired on September 30, 2010, 4:10 AM. The current time is March 17, 2018, 10:54 AM. Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

I'm using FireFox, but I get the error on Safari and Chrome as well. How can I get around this?

Comment: `The certificate expired`, `UNKNOWN_ISSUER` -> what unclear is in the error message you are seeing?

Comment: this is the error code:

Comment: Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `.local` or `.test` instead of `.dev`.

In chrome and firefox `.dev` domains are now redirected to HTTPS via a preloaded HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header.

For more info https://content.nanobox.io/google-chrome-now-forces-all-dev-domains-to-https/

Comment: Thank you so much! I also used the *.dev for my localhost development. Switching to *.local helped.